# Float right is not using same bottom margin as float left

Tags: html, css, css-float

For some reason my object that is floated right is not displaying the same as the one I'm floating left in Firefox. The one on the right has no margin at the bottom against the footer, and the one on the left has the desired result. Any idea why it does this?  Here is my CSS and my HTML:

CSS:

```
p {
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
}

#container {
overflow:hidden;
width: 100%;
max-width:960px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#branding {
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:black;
z-align:1000;
}

#logo {
background-image:url("images/google-logo-small.png");
height:69px;
width:200px;
margin:15px 0 0 10px;
float:left;
z-align:1001;
}

#toparea {
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
margin:20px 0px 20px 0;
float:right;
color:white;
z-align:1001;
}

#toparea ul li {
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
padding:0 30px 20px 0;
}

#topcontent {
width:100%;
background-color:inherit;
margin:0;
z-align:1000;
}

#blockone {
border-radius: 15px;
width:48%;
height:200px;
background-color:gray;
float:left;
border-width:1px;
border-color:black;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#blockone p {
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
font-size:20px;
color: white;
padding:20px 0 0 20px;
}

#blocktwo {
border-radius: 15px;
width:48%;
height:200px;
float:right;
background-color:gray;
border-width:1px;
border-color:black;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#blocktwo p {
font-size:20px;
color: white;
padding:20px 0 0 20px;
}

#footer {
clear:both;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
border-radius: 15px;
width:100%;
height:200px;
background-color:gray;
border-width:1px;
border-color:black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='css/base.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>


<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="branding">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="toparea">
            <ul>
                <li>Content</li>
                <li>Content2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="topcontent">
                <div id="blockone">
                <p>some copy</p>
                </div>

                <div id="blocktwo">
                <p>this is more text</p></div>
                </div>
        <div id="footer"><p>Some more copy</p></div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have two extra closing `</div>` tags in your HTML. Remove them and your two floated divs will behave the same. Incorrectly, but the same. Also, Z-align is not a valid CSS property. You might mean `z-index`, but that won't work unless you have `position` declared as `fixed`, `relative`, or `absolute`.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yaqJ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Margins of sibling elements inside the same element add up. To correct this, replace this...

```css
#blocktwo {
    border-radius: 15px;
    width:48%;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    background-color:gray;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

... with this...

```css
#blocktwo {
    border-radius: 15px;
    width:48%;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    background-color:gray;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* <-- this is what I changed */
}
```

**[HERE IS A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LeVB2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have different margins set for the item you're floating left, and the item you are floating right. You also need to ensure they have the same height if you want them to display lined up with the same margins. Also, Z-Align is not valid CSS.

Try this:

```
#logo {
background-image:url("images/google-logo-small.png");
height:69px;
width:200px;
margin:15px 0 0 10px;
float:left;
}

#toparea {
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
height:69px;
margin:15px 0 0 10px;
float:right;
color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#toparea {
margin:20px 0px 20px 0;
}`

This is your problem.  The bottom margin on the navigation div is pushing the content below it.  Remove the bottom margin and it will behave as expected.